# Rename the column headers in a graphite/grafana table panel

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have a table pan which is time series aggregation.  I'm happy with everything exception of the labels, which are "Metric" and "Current", provided by Grafana or Graphite.

Is it possible for me to override these labels?